# Writing a sentence in past tense in French

Tags: passé-composé

I read the following sentence in French:

> Le Parlement a modifié la loi.

Does the above sentence mean?

> The parlement changed the law

In this case, cannot we write the above sentence as:

> Le Parlement modifié la loi.

In other words, why is *to* included here?

Answer (score 4):

> Does the above sentence mean?
>
> "The parlement changed the law"

Yes, this is the right translation.

> In other words, why is to included here?

You're mistaken on the use of "a". It's not used as "to" (à) but as the verb "to have".

**Avoir** modifié la loi. Passé composé avec l'auxilière avoir. Voir [ici](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/modifier.php) pour la conjugaison complète.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I remove `a`, wouldn't it be correct?

Comment: No it wouldn't. I suggest you read about "conjugaison du passé composé" to learn more. It is perhaps one of the most complex grammatical rule to learn... you'll need good bases. There are too much particularities to explain this in an answer/comment.